# Extract price with curl command

Tags: curl

I try to extract some information with curl command
With a simple grep I extract the title:

`grep -o "<title>[^<]*" | sed -e 's/<[^>]*>//g'`

but I would like to extract the price of the product. If I check the code I see this inside of this content:

$(document).ready(function(){$('.sequra-product-price-js').text('***27,62 €***');$('.sequra-product-price-js').attr('content','27.62');$('.descuento_marca_producto').html

How can extract the price?

This is for example an URL:

curl -k https://bulevip.com/es/pre-entreno/20927-cellucor-c4-original-pre-workout-390-gr-60-servicios.html

thanks!

Comment: your title extractor will fail on any HTML-encoded characters. for example, if the title is `<title>bl&aring;b&aelig;rsyltet&oslash;y</title>`, the correct translation is `blåbærsyltetøy` (norwegian for `blueberry jam`), but your extractor will end up with `bl&aring;b&aelig;rsyltet&oslash;y`, completely unreadable. it will also fail if the title includes special characters like `&` or `<` or `>` or `^` - to get the correct translation, you could instead do: `php -r 'echo (@DOMDocument::loadHTML(stream_get_contents(STDIN)))->getElementsByTagName("title")->item(0)->textContent;'`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

php-cli's DOMDocument + DOMXPath can easily extract the price,

```
curl -ks https://bulevip.com/es/pre-entreno/20927-cellucor-c4-original-pre-workout-390-gr-60-servicios.html | php -r 'echo (new DOMXPath(@DOMDocument::loadHTML(stream_get_contents(STDIN))))->query("//span[contains(@class,\"product-price-js\")]")->item(0)->getAttribute("content");'
```

btw [you should not parse HTML with regex.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/1067003)

for example, you say that you already have title extraction working with

```
grep -o "<title>[^<]*" | sed -e 's/<[^>]*>//g'
```

but it is flawed, it will fail on any HTML-encoded characters. for example, if the title is `<title>bl&aring;b&aelig;rsyltet&oslash;y</title>`, the correct translation is `blåbærsyltetøy` (norwegian for blueberry jam), but your extractor will end up with `bl&aring;b&aelig;rsyltet&oslash;y`, which is completely unreadable. it will also fail if the title includes special characters like `&` or `<` or `>` or `^` - to get the correct translation, you could instead do:

```
php -r 'echo (@DOMDocument::loadHTML(stream_get_contents(STDIN)))->getElementsByTagName("title")->item(0)->textContent;'
```

which will correctly translate any html-encoded character :)

and if we put it to the test:

```
$ echo '<title>bl&aring;b&aelig;rsyltet&oslash;y</title>' > html

$ cat html | grep -o "<title>[^<]*" | sed -e 's/<[^>]*>//g'
bl&aring;b&aelig;rsyltet&oslash;y

$ cat html | php -r 'echo (@DOMDocument::loadHTML(stream_get_contents(STDIN)))->getElementsByTagName("title")->item(0)->textContent;'
blåbærsyltetøy

$
```

or if the title is `AT&T` (the world's largest telecom company, from USA), which must be encoded as `AT&amp;T`,

```
$ echo '<title>AT&amp;T</title>' > html

$ cat html | grep -o "<title>[^<]*" | sed -e 's/<[^>]*>//g'
AT&amp;T

$ cat html | php -r 'echo (@DOMDocument::loadHTML(stream_get_contents(STDIN)))->getElementsByTagName("title")->item(0)->textContent;'
AT&T
```